# Error while installing rails

Tags: 11.10, ruby, rails, sqlite, gem

Following this [tutorial](http://cicolink.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-install-ruby-rails-and.html#!http://cicolink.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-install-ruby-rails-and.html) here, to install `ruby on rails` on `ubuntu 11.10` with `sqlite3`

when I run the following command

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I get the following error :

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

Also, when I try the command,

```
sudo gem install sqlite3
```

I get the same error

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sqlite3' (>= 0) in any repository

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Rails is not available for Ruby 1.9.1 - so if you remove Ruby 1.9.1, you can choose: either you use [RVM](http://www.the-tech-tutorial.com/?p=1868) to install Ruby 1.9.2 or you install Ruby 1.8 and you should be able to install Rails (however, using a older version of Ruby == older version of Rails afaik) :)

(I'm using RVM, which I like as it gives me the opportunity to switch between different installations of Ruby and also develop without having to be root - however I would read more about how RVM works before using it on a production server)

Comment: Oh, sorry, noticed you're not using apt-get to install Ruby. However, try downgrading to 1.9.2 anyways that is tested to work with Rails or try compiling Rails yourself (http://rubyonrails.org/download)

Comment: My ruby version (from `ruby -v`) is `1.9.3p0` and my gem version (from `gem -v`) is `1.8.15`  .. rubyonrails.org says that `rails 3.2` is recommended for `ruby 1.9.3` .. I have the right versions (from what I've read) .. Can you give me the steps for the RVM installation how I can switch versions?

Comment: The site I linked (http://www.the-tech-tutorial.com/?p=1868) is quite good (I'm quite sure I used it) - replace 1.9.2 with 1.9.3 and see if that work, however your error seems to have something to do with something else! I'll try to help you look for a solution w/ Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue using the proxy command option of gem install. It has the following format:

```
$ gem install --http-proxy http://201.187.107.19:8080 rails
```

Check the following [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203632/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-rails-0-in-any-repository) for more details.