# Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: 12.04, apt, ruby, rails, gem

I am trying to install rails using the following command:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

and get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rails
```

I am using:

1. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2. My Ruby version is ruby

   ```
   1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
   ```
3. My gem version is

   ```
   $gem -v
   1.8.11
   ```

I have try some things that I found in the net like trying to update my gem version using the following command:

```
gem update --system
```

but it throws me un error again:

```
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
     gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break
 your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update
 rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories. If
 you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by
 setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please
 remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.
```

Could you advice what should i try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue using the proxy command option of gem install. It has the following format:

```
$ gem install --http-proxy http://201.187.107.19:8080 rails
```

Note, the IP address and the port number refers to a proxy. You should search for a proxy list and use one of the proxies there.

This is site with proxies: http://www.cybersyndrome.net/pla5.html

Also, I have to try 7 or 8 different proxies in order to succeed. Do not give up.

Note, you could see the following error, too:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires activesupport (= 3.2.8), actionpack (= 3.2.8), activerecord (= 3.2.8), activeresource (= 3.2.8), actionmailer (= 3.2.8), railties (= 3.2.8), bundler (~> 1.0)
```

Don't give up and continue with the next proxy from the list. Good luck.